# std::unique_ptr<T[]> and custom allocator deleter

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, unique-ptr, allocator

I am trying to use `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` with custom memory allocators. Basically, I have custom allocators that are subclasses of `IAllocator`, which provides the following methods:

```
void* Alloc( size_t size )
template<typename T> T* AllocArray( size_t count )
void Free( void* mem )
template<typename T> void FreeArray( T* arr, size_t count )
```

Since the underlying memory might come from a pre-allocated block, I need the special `...Array()`-methods to allocate and free arrays, they allocate/free memory and call `T()` / `~T()` on every element in the range.
Now, as far as I know, custom deleters for `std::unique_ptr` use the signature:

```
void operator()(T* ptr) const
```

In the case of `unique_ptr<T[]>`, normally you would call `delete[]` and be done with it, but I have to call `FreeArray<T>`, for which I need the number of elements in the range. Given only the raw pointer, I think there is no way of obtaining the size of the range, hence the only thing I could come up with is this:

```
std::unique_ptr<T[], MyArrDeleter> somePtr( allocator.AllocArray<T>( 20 ), MyArrDeleter( allocator, 20 ) );
```

Where essentially the size of the array has to be passed into the deleter object manually. Is there a better way to do this? This seems quite error-prone to me...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there most certainly is a better way:
Use a maker-function.

```
template<class T, class A> std::unique_ptr<T[], MyArrDeleter>
my_maker(size_t count, A&& allocator) {
    return {somePtr(allocator.AllocArray<T>(count), MyArrDeleter(allocator, count)};
}

auto p = my_maker<T>(42, allocator);
```

Answer (score 0):

`T*` doesn't contain such information, neither unique_ptr knows about the size of the array (since it uses directly a `delete []` as you stated). You could let the `T` be a `unique_ptr<T>` to manage the destruction automatically but this could not be possible if the whole contiguous `T*` is managed by a memory allocator (and not a single `T*` object). Eg:

```
unique_ptr<unique_ptr<Foo>[]> data;
data.reset(new unique_ptr<Foo>[50]);
data[0].reset(new Foo());
```