# Why is a unique_ptr not freed after a constructor calls an exception?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

In the following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

void mydeallocator(int * x) {
    std::cerr << "Freeing memory" << std::endl;
    delete x;
}

struct Foo {
    std::unique_ptr <int,std::function <void(int*)>> x;
    Foo(bool fail) : x(new int(1),mydeallocator) {
        if(fail)
            throw std::runtime_error("We fail here");
    }
};

int main() {
    {auto foo1 = Foo(false);}
    {auto foo2 = Foo(true);}
}
```

It appears that memory is not being deallocated properly when `Foo(true)` is called.  Namely, when we compile and run this program, we have the result:

```
Freeing memory
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  We fail here
Aborted
```

I believe that the message `Freeing memory` should be called twice.  Basically, according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197566/is-it-ever-not-safe-to-throw-an-exception-in-a-constructor) and the ISO C++ folks [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#ctors-can-throw) and [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#selfcleaning-members), my understanding is that the stack should unwind on the constructor for `Foo` and that `x` should call its destructor, which should call `mydeallocator`.  Certainly, this is not happening, so why is the memory not being freed?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Foo's constructor is throwing the exception, not the constructor of `unique_ptr`. Since `x` has been fully constructed when the exception is thrown the destructor of `unique_ptr` should be invoked for `x`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant `~Foo()` would not be run, but `~unique_ptr()` should be - no?

Comment: It's not just that, because you're not catching the exception, you're losing the console output due to the program aborting?

Comment: Oh, wait, you `throw;` without an active exception. That goes straight to `terminate`. No stack unwinding happens at all.

Comment: @T.C. The same error will occur with a runtime_error.  One moment and I'll fix the question.

Comment: You do not catch the exception, so the execution goes to `terminate()` before the unique_ptr is freed. If you add a `catch` handler you will see both messages.

Comment: BTW: If you don't really need the flexibility of using a `std::function`, consider reducing it to a simple pointer. Or preferably an empty function-object. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413035 for a function making that easier.

Comment: If an exception escapes `main()` then it is implementation defined if the stack is unwound. That's why you should catch everything in main() and log/rethrow (if you want to force stack unwinding).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your original code `throw;` when you have nothing to rethrow. That causes `std::terminate` to be called; the stack is not unwound (and hence the destructors don't run).

Your new code throws an exception without handling it. In that case whether the stack is unwound is implementation-defined, so it's still perfectly conforming to `terminate()` right away. [except.terminate], emphasis mine:

> In some situations exception handling must be abandoned for less
>   subtle error handling techniques. [ *Note*: These situations are:
>
> - when the exception handling mechanism, after completing the initialization of the exception object but before activation of a
>     handler for the exception (15.1), calls a function that exits via an
>     exception, or
> - **when the exception handling mechanism cannot find a handler for a thrown exception (15.3)**, or
> - when the search for a handler (15.3) encounters the outermost block of a function with a noexcept-specification that does not allow the
>     exception (15.4), or
> - when the destruction of an object during stack unwinding (15.2) terminates by throwing an exception, or
> - when initialization of a non-local variable with static or thread storage duration (3.6.2) exits via an exception, or
> - when destruction of an object with static or thread storage duration exits via an exception (3.6.3), or
> - when execution of a function registered with `std::atexit` or `std::at_quick_exit` exits via an exception (18.5), or
> - **when a *throw-expression* (5.17) with no operand attempts to rethrow an exception and no exception is being handled (15.1)**, or
> - when `std::unexpected` exits via an exception of a type that is not allowed by the previously violated exception specification, and
>     std::bad_exception is not included in that exception specification
>     (15.5.2), or
> - when the implementation’s default unexpected exception handler is called (D.8.1), or
> - when the function `std::nested_exception::rethrow_nested` is called for an object that has captured no exception (18.8.6), or
> - when execution of the initial function of a thread exits via an exception (30.3.1.2), or
> - when the destructor or the copy assignment operator is invoked on an object of type `std::thread` that refers to a joinable thread
>     (30.3.1.3, 30.3.1.4), or
> - when a call to a `wait()`, `wait_until()`, or `wait_for()` function on a condition variable (30.5.1, 30.5.2) fails to meet a
>     postcondition. —*end note* ]
>
> In such cases, `std::terminate()` is called (18.8.3). **In the situation
>   where no matching handler is found, it is implementation-defined
>   whether or not the stack is unwound before `std::terminate()` is
>   called.** In the situation where the search for a handler (15.3)
>   encounters the outermost block of a function with a
>   *noexcept-specification* that does not allow the exception (15.4), it is implementation-defined whether the stack is unwound, unwound
>   partially, or not unwound at all before `std::terminate()` is called.
>   **In all other situations, the stack shall not be unwound before
>   `std::terminate()` is called.** An implementation is not permitted to
>   finish stack unwinding prematurely based on a determination that the
>   unwind process will eventually cause a call to `std::terminate()`.

Comment: What's the right way to free the memory then?  If I add a try-catch block inside the constructor that rethrows the exception, we still leak.  What I'd like to have happen is for the memory to be freed even when an exception is called regardless if my user writes a try-catch block around the initialization of the class.

Comment: @wyer33 If the user doesn't catch the exception, the whole program is going to crash and burn, so why do you care if the memory is freed?

Comment: @wyer33 Try/catch in main

Comment: @T.C. Well, in my actual case, I've a pointer to a database and I'd like to clean up some entries before the program terminates.  Normally, I do that with a custom deallocator on a unique_ptr.

Comment: @wyer33 OK, then call `reset()` on the `unique_ptr` to force clean-up before you rethrow the exception.

Comment: @T.C. Alright, that works.  Also, what's odd is that if I use a function-try-block `Foo(bool fail) try : x(new int(1),mydeallocator) {...} catch(...) { throw; }`, everything deallocates properly.  Is this reliable or does that fall into the implementation defined unwinding?  Note, the same does not occur if I use a try-catch block inside the constructor.  The function-try-block is required.

Comment: @wyer33 Yes, you can rely on the function-try-block. All fully-constructed subobjects are destroyed before entering its handler.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for the help!  In case someone else is looking, I believe that the relevent section is 15.3.11 `The fully constructed base classes and members of an object shall be destroyed before entering the handler
of a function-try-block of a constructor for that object.`