# trivial allocator aware container?

Tags: c++, allocator

I am studying/playing with allocators trying to understand how it works. But I run into problems trying to implement trivial container that accepts an allocator. For now I ended up with this:

```
template<class T, class Allocator =std::allocator<T>> class Container {
public:
    using allocator_type    = Allocator;
    using value_type        = T;
    using pointer           = typename std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::pointer;
    using reference         = value_type&;
    using size_type         = std::size_t;

    Container( size_type n =0 , const allocator_type& allocator =allocator_type() ){
        std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl;
        allocator.allocate(n);
    };
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){
    Container<int> c {5};
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me an error `member function 'allocate' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const allocator_type' (aka 'const std::__1::allocator<int>'), but function is not marked const`

How to fix that error, please? Am I missing something ?
I intend to use traits later but would like to make it work using the old way first.

Comment: It is not the function but it is `allocator` that is marked `const`.  You might want to look at how libc++, libstdc++ implement this in something like `std::vector`.

Comment: standard containers usually use this const reference to initialize their own  member (or base class) and than call allocate on this member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line

```
allocator.allocate(n);
```

attempts to call the `allocate` method of `allocator`, which is not defined as a `const` method. If you look, though, the type of `allocator` is `const allocator_type&`, that is, a const reference to `allocator_type`.

How can you use it then? One thing you can usually do with a const object (or reference to one) is to construct a different non-const object from it. This, for example, builds:

```
allocator_type(allocator).allocate(n);
```

As SergeyA correctly notes in the comments, it is fairly common not to construct a temporary ad-hoc `allocator_type`, but rather make such a member:

```
    allocator_type m_alloc; // Should probably be private

    Container( size_type n =0 , const allocator_type& allocator =allocator_type() ) : 
            m_alloc{allocator}{
        std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl;
        m_alloc.allocate(n);
    };
```

Comment: Would it be a bad practice to const_cast it away? Although making it a member seems pretty natural and elegant.

Comment: @JiříLechner `const_cast`s are usually a clear sign of some problem. Here, also, as you note, there's a very natural way to bypass it, so why not?

Comment: One more question. I would like to use unique_ptr. Is it a good idea making a specialisation of an allocator that would return a unique_ptr or is it out of scope of the allocator's job?

Comment: @JiříLechner Actually, if you use a `unique_ptr`, you'd probably just want to [set your allocator's `deallocate` as its deallocator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413035/stdunique-ptrt-and-custom-allocator-deleter). I would personally avoid this direction. If you're indeed writing a container, it's one of the rare cases where it's probably just simpler to have the destructor explicitly deallocate the memory.

Comment: you mean set the unique_ptr's deleter to allocator's deallocate()?

Comment: @JiříLechner That's what I meant, yes.

Comment: hm, what I have understood it is allowed to make an allocator that yields a user-defined class as a pointer to the allocated resource.Am I right? Since unique_ptr accepts only real pointers I must implement a deleter that will provide the translation...